# Hide anchor href with jQuery based on its title

Tags: jquery, html, css, href

I have the following html

```
<li class="static">
 <a title="blog" class="static menu-item" href="http://google.com">Blog</a>
</li>

<li class="static">
 <a title="profile" class="static menu-item" href="http://profile.com">Profile</a>
</li>

<li class="static">
 <a title="site2" class="static menu-item" href="http://site-2.com">Site-2</a>
</li>
```

I need to hide the above links (only the link to Blog and Profile) based on their title attribute only. What would be the easiest way to do it via jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Try this:

```
$('[title=blog],[title=profile]').hide()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.static a[title='blog'], .static a[title='profile']
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not jQuery as the OP wanted... I like it more though!

Answer (score 3):

Although you noted you want a jQuery solution, note that you can actually do this purely in CSS:

```
a[title=blog], a[title=site2]{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I need to hide the above links (only the link to Blog and Profile)
>   based on their title attribute only.

Use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and combine selectors using [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('a[title=profile], a[title=site2]').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[title=profile], a[title=site2]').hide()
})
```

Do it using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above answers, if the hidden links need to be dynamic, you could address this by using an array of the titles as follows:

```
var titleArray = ['blog', 'profile'];

function hideLinks(titleArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < titleArray.length; i++) {
        $('a[title='+titleArray[i]+']').hide();
    }
}

hideLinks(titleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("a").each(function(){

   if($(this).attr("title") != "site2"){
        $(this).hide();                
    } 

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxcfY/